# Unable click on the link button of email template using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to identify the link residing in an email body template using selenium webdriver?

I was trying to automate a scenario where I will receive an email with a body having a link to click to complete the registration process.

Using a public mail server I was able to login into a web-based email provider with Selenium. I clicked on the email which I received but web driver was not able to identify the link using ID webelement locator enclosed in the email body template. After execution I am ending up with the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"enrollmentURL"}

HTML of email link:

```html
<a id="enrollmentURL" href="click1.clickrouter.com/…; style="font-family: &quot;arial&quot; , &quot;helvetica&quot; , sans-serif ; font-size: 16px ; line-height: 16px ; color: #fff ; text-decoration: none ; display: block" target="_other" rel="nofollow"><strong>GET&nbsp;STARTED</strong></a>
```

Code:

```
Generic.waitForElement(malinatoremailid,1,driver); 
Generic.click(malinatoremailid,driver); 
Generic.enterText(malinatoremailid,map.get(0).get("Email"),d‌​river); 
Generic.click(go,driver); Generic.waitForElement(email,2,driver); 
Generic.click(email,driver);
```

Comment: Which public email server are you using and can you also post the HTML of the required areas, and your selenium code.

Comment: @Hac:Iam using mailinator.com mail server and the details mentioned:<a id="enrollmentURL" href="http://click1.clickrouter.com/redirect?token=a2258079c24c4c50a56b6b1ffb75d6e2&amp;url=http%3A//54.82.136.72%3A8080/web/vwcwp/login%3Ftoken%3D899facd9-d3b2-d668-4531-84307cac1eff" style="font-family: &quot;arial&quot; , &quot;helvetica&quot; , sans-serif ; font-size: 16px ; line-height: 16px ; color: #fff ; text-decoration: none ; display: block" target="_other" rel="nofollow"><strong>GET&nbsp;STARTED</strong></a>

Comment: Generic.waitForElement(malinatoremailid,1,driver);
        Generic.click(malinatoremailid,driver);
        Generic.enterText(malinatoremailid,map.get(0).get("Email"),driver);
        Generic.click(go,driver);
        Generic.waitForElement(email,2,driver);
        Generic.click(email,driver);

Comment: I want to click on the above enorllment URL id locator enclosed in an email template body that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to check out one of the sample emails from mailinator https://www.mailinator.com/v2/inbox.jsp?zone=public&query=HeadyPie#/#msgpane

If you look further up in the html, you will see that the email body is contained under an iframe. So after clicking on the email, you will first have to switch to that iframe before clicking the link:

```
// Click on the email

// Now switch to the email body iframe:
driver.switchTo().frame("msg_body");

// Click on the email link 

// If you need to go back to the menu, don't forget to switch back:
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Yay! Glad it worked. And thanks for accepting my answer too.

Comment: Thank u! I spent 1 hour, could understand what's the problem.